# ndk build and .so file creation android

Tags: android, android-ndk

i am new in android ndk.

I am working on a app which needs java code as well c/c++ code

So, for that i  need android ndk.

But i stuck at this point that i cannot run ndk-build which makes the connection between java and c/c++.

So. please someone help me out to solve this problem.

I tried on both windows and linux but got same error.

I got this error when i use ndk-build .

```
/home/kamal/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/add-application.mk:128: Android NDK:      
Compile thumb : ndk <= native.c
jni/native.c: In function 'Java_com_example_demo_MainActivity_hello':  
jni/native.c:4:3: error: parameter name omitted
jni/native.c:4:3: error: parameter name omitted
jni/native.c:5:10: error: 'env' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native.c:5:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each              function it appears in
jni/native.c: In function 'Java_com_example_demo_MainActivity_add':
jni/native.c:9:3: error: parameter name omitted
jni/native.c:9:3: error: parameter name omitted
jni/native.c:9:3: error: parameter name omitted
jni/native.c:9:3: error: parameter name omitted
jni/native.c:10:9: error: 'value1' undeclared (first use in this function) 
jni/native.c:10:18: error: 'value2' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/myjni/native.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all you are getting this error because you are not declaring parameter in is must to create conection between java and c/c++.

SO, i am sending you my code for your problem

1.First of all create android project in eclipse.

2. create folder under project click  -> click new -> then folder and name it jni.
3. create one more folder under jni nameing include.
4. create java class.
5. code for java class nameing-(MainActivity.java)->

   ```
    package com.example.ndk;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("myjni");
       }

   /**
   * Adds two integers, returning their sum
   */
   public native int add( int v1, int v2 );

   /**
   * Returns Hello World string
   */
   public native String hello();


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
   }

       }
   ```
6. open command prompt or press window+R.
7. move to directory- (workspace-> project name -> jni -> include).
8. run command under this directory.

   ```
       javah -classpath <project-name>/bin/classes;<ANDROID_SDK_HOME>\platforms\android-<xx>\android.jar -o HelloJNI.h com.example.test.MainActivity
   ```
9. after this we can see  "HelloJNI.h"  file under include folder.
10. check "HelloJNI.h" have this lines in it

    ```
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_ndk_MainActivity_add(JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);

    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_ndk_MainActivity_hello (JNIEnv *, jobject);
    ```
11. create new file under jni naming test.c (use this 2 points in pont 10 in this file test.c)

    ```
       #include <jni.h>
       #include "include/HelloJNI.h"

    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_ndk_MainActivity_hello
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject javaThis) {
        return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello");
    }

      JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_ndk_MainActivity_add
          (JNIEnv *env, jobject javaThis, jint value1, jint value2){
    return (value1 + value2);
        }
    ```
12. create new file under jni naming Android.mk

    ```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE    := myjni       // from point 5 
     LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.c     //from point 10 that we creare test.c

     include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
    ```
13. create new file NDKActivity.java

    ```
      package com.example.ndk;

      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.EditText;
      import android.widget.TextView;

      public class NDKActivity extends Activity{

      Button buttonCalc;
      TextView result;
      EditText value1,value2;
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      MainActivity nativeLib;
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     nativeLib = new MainActivity();
      String helloText = nativeLib.hello();

    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    value1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.value1);
    value2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.value2);

    // Update the UI
    TextView outText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textOut);
    outText.setText(helloText);

     // Setup the UI
    buttonCalc = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.buttonCalc);

    buttonCalc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View v) {
     int v1, v2, res = -1;
     v1 = Integer.parseInt(value1.getText().toString().trim());
     v2 = Integer.parseInt(value2.getText().toString().trim());

     res = nativeLib.add(v1, v2);
     result.setText(new Integer(res).toString());
     }



     });
     }
         }
    ```
14. run ndk-build in command promt

go to project directory-> then, write this command `<android-ndk-directory>\ndk-build.cmd` and hit enter

after this we can check .so file under obj folder

14. xml file for NDKActivity.

    ```
     <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Vikram"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textOut"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Output"/>

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/value1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Value 1"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="+"
         android:textSize="36sp" />

          <EditText
       android:id="@+id/value2"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="Value 2"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/buttonCalc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="=" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="result"
       android:textSize="36sp" />


       </LinearLayout>
    ```

Comment: @Vikram ... when i am trying to run  javah -classpath <project-name>/bin/classes;<ANDROID_SDK_HOME>\platforms\android-<xx>\android.jar -o HelloJNI.h com.example.test.MainActivity...... I am getting this exception in console "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainClassFromJar(Unknown Source)
 at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

Comment: nice answer! thank you man!!! just one correction for gradle project. in point 7 we should substitude <project-name>/bin/classes with <project-name>\build\intermediates\classes\debug (or release)

Comment: @GrafOrlov i am trying to run this command  But i am fail to to run Point 7 it show class not Found Error: Could not find class file for 'com.example.encrcytionexample.MainActivity
'.  I have done it in Eclipse

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be that this is function mis-match in .h file and .cpp file. 
You have mentioned some parameters in functions in .h file which are missing in implementation in native.cpp files.

Comment: Hey Kirti, I searched my parameters but m unable to find. Thanx for reply